# Update userform multiple textboxes automatically when editing

Tags: excel, vba, date

When I edit(update) a record, I would like to automatically update subsequent due dates when textbox1 DueDate is updated. Currently, I am having to tab through each textbox in order for the due date to be recalculated. There are 17 DueDate textboxes so I am wondering if there is an easier way so the end user doesn't have to tab through each textbox if Textbox1 due date changes from 1/1/2023 to 2/1/2023. Below is the screen shot of the Due Date textboxes from the userform and the code that I am using for each textbox.

[image: Userform DueDate textboxes]

```
Private Sub txtDueDate1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

If txtBusCal2.Value = "Calendar" Then
txtDueDate2.Value = CDate(txtDueDate1.Value) + (txtDays2.Value)
txtDueDate2.Value = Format(CDate(txtDueDate2.Value))

Else
txtDueDate2.Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(CDate(txtDueDate1.Value), txtDays2.Value)
txtDueDate2.Value = Format(CDate(txtDueDate2.Value))

End If
End Sub
```

For each textbox, I use the _Exit event since _Change or _AfterUpdate wasn't working.

Comment: Just curious, what is `txtBusCal2` and `txtDays2` ? A control ? what control ? textbox ? label ? never fix --->  this time maybe a textbox, another time maybe a label ?

Comment: Hi Karma - txtBusCal1 thru 17 & txtDays1 thru 17 are all textboxes and I just changed the background color to grey since they are default values when launching the form. I am not very experienced in VBA and figured it would be easier to make them textboxes and allow the end user to overwrite those values if there are any changes in the future versus having to constantly update labels. I hope this information helps.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. If all textboxes name has pattern (blablabla with sequential number suffix), I think maybe you can try to loop use the keydown event sub for your txtDueDate1, something like this : `if keycode=vbkeyreturn Then: for i = 2 to 17:  set tdd = "txtDueDate" & i: If controls("txtBusCal" & i) .Value = "Calendar" Then tdd.Value = CDate(controls("txtDueDate" & i-1).Value) + (controsl("txtDays" & i).Value): 
tdd.Value = Format(CDate(tdd.Value))` ... and so on. Since you say _if Textbox1 due date changes_ ... so the loop is for when txtDueDate1 change.

Comment: Karma - Thank you for the information. I keep getting either an object error or invalid qualifier for TDD.  (Set TDD = "txtDueDate" & i) . It is probably something simple and user error. Again, thank you for your help and I will figure it out to make it work.

Comment: Roe, very sorry that i made typo in my comment. (1) i forget to put "controls"... So it should be: `set tdd = controls("txtDieDate"&i)`. 2. It should be `controls` not `controsl`. In short, you need the word "controls" to refer to your textbox name.

Comment: Hi Karma - Thank you for the update. I just updated the code and it works!!!!!!. You are the best..  I decided to add a command button and placed the code there. Also, I wanted to make it easier for the end user.  Again, thank you very much.